# Iterate objects inside objects in react

Tags: reactjs

I have this objects inside objects that I wanted to iterate in react

```
const [PersonInfo, setPersonInfo] = useState({
 {name: "Juan", address: "Street1"},
 {name: "Kristine", address: "Street2"}
}
```

I tried to render it in react using

```
return (
  <div>
    {{Object.keys(PersonInfo).map(key => 
        <option value={key}>{PersonInfo[key]}</option>
      )}
  </div>
)
```

But it only shows the first value which is Juan. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The first snippet has incorrect syntax.

Comment: the data you pass to `useState` is not valid, and the code will not run. Please show some working sample.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli  default value in useState is {}. and I add new object using  setPersonInfo({...PersonInfo,  
              name: "Juan",
              address: "street1",
            })

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors, what you should do instead is save `array` insde your `useState` and loop over it using `.map`

```
const [personsInfo, setPersonsInfo] = useState([
  {name: "Juan", address: "Street1"},
  {name: "Kristine", address: "Street2"}
])
```

After that you can render it like so:

```
  return (
    <select name="personAddress">
      {personsInfo.map(person => {
        return (
          <option key={person.name} value={person.address}>{person.name}</option>
         )
      })}
    </select>
  );
```

This example assumes that each person has a unique name. Therefore the `key={person.name}`.